# jquery two functions interfer: they overlay

Tags: jquery, smarty

I am using two jQuery functions: One in the header (dropdown replacement) and one in the content part (graphical presentation of available item's year). My problem is that they overlay. How can I put the dropdown function one layer above the second function?

[image]

I am thankful for any hint!

Comment: are you able to style the elements with z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a [z-index](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/) CSS property to the element being in the background.

Be aware that both elements (the one you like to bring to front and the one currently overlapping it) need to be in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) for z-index to work.